# Two Backgrounds on Website. Facing two problems

Tags: html, css, background, web

I would like to add two backgrounds to my website, but I am facing some problems there.

1. Problem
   The first one is a photo, which should be scrollable to the end of the photo and not repeating itself. 
   Sometimes my webpage becomes longer than the photo. Is there a method to define the maximum length of the website
2. Problem
   The second Background is a box, which contains some info like can be seen on the bottom of this website: [Logofaves](http://www.logofaves.com/)

I would like this Box to always be in a certain distance to the content. Even if I havent got a lot of content the Box should be a bit further up and not on the bottom of the photo.

I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: What have you tried? Which part are you unable to do? Did you try `max-height` + `overflow:hidden`?

Comment: "What have you tried? Which part are you unable to do?" Why do people always skip that part?

Answer (score 0):

This is basic CSS, you should link example code if you really want a precise answer.

Nevertheless,

1. For the first point you can use :
   body {
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   }
   or if you want to fix the height of a div (for instance called #content) just do :
   #content {
   margin: 0;
   height: 100%;
   overflow-y: auto;
   }
2. I'm not sure to understand the second point. Why can't you do what you whant with position+margin property ?